# Add same object to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I've created a shopping cart, and right now the the cart contains a single apple, a single orange, and the total prices.

How would I add a second "apple" without creating another object?

For example, I now would like to add 2 apples to the cart, so the price in the array gets updated, as well as the total amount.

```
module.exports = {
  shoppingCart: function () {
    //create empty cart array
    theCart = [];
    // create two seperate versions of the same kind of object using class method
    class Fruits {
      constructor(fruit, price) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
        this.price = price;
        // this.quantity = price * 2;
      }
    }
    let fruit1 = new Fruits('Apple', 4.95); // create new object. sets the value of this
    let fruit2 = new Fruits('Orange', 3.99);
    let fruit3 = new Fruits('Total amount', fruit1.price + fruit2.price);

    // combine both fruits into an array
    let bothFruits = [fruit1, fruit2, fruit3];

    //add items to the cart
    Array.prototype.push.apply(theCart, bothFruits);
    //remove items from the cart by calling this function
    function removeAllItems() {
      if ((theCart.length = !0)) {
        theCart = [];
      }
    }
    //removeAllItems();

    console.log(theCart);
  },
};
```

Comment: Loop through items in `theCart` and when you get to the "apple", update its `price` attribute to 9.0 (2*4.95). When you get to the "Total amount" item, update its price to the running total. Of course, this is all assuming you want to continue to use the same data structure, which I would not recommend because it is difficult to manipulate. Better would be to store the price and quantity of each item (see the answer given by Roby Raju Oommen), but also store the total separately, since it's not really an item in the cart.

Comment: Thanks kmoser, very helpful as I believe you are correct in storing the total amount seperately, so that is what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
class Fruits {
    constructor() {
        this.items = [];
        this.totals = 0;
    }

    calculateTotals() {
        this.totals = 0;
        this.items.forEach(item => {
            let price = item.price;
            let quantity = item.quantity;
            let amount = price * quantity;
            this.totals += amount;
        });
    }

    addToCart(fruit, price, quantity) {
        let obj = { fruit, price, quantity }
        this.items.push(obj);
        this.calculateTotals();
    }

    get cart() {
        return { items: this.items, totals: this.totals }
    }
}

const fruitsCart = new Fruits();

fruitsCart.addToCart("Apple", 10.5, 2);
fruitsCart.addToCart("Orang", 15, 1);

const cart = fruitsCart.cart;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to add the quantity also. Please try the following code:

```
module.exports = {
shoppingCart: function () {
    //create empty cart array
    theCart = [];
    // create two seperate versions of the same kind of object using class method 
    class Fruits {
        constructor(fruit, price, quantity) {
            this.fruit = fruit;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.price = price * quantity;
            
        }
    }
    let fruit1 = new Fruits("Apple", 4.95, 2);       // create new object. sets the value of this
    let fruit2 = new Fruits("Orange", 3.99, 1);
    let fruit3 = new Fruits("Total amount", fruit1.price + fruit2.price);
    
    // combine both fruits into an array
    let bothFruits = [fruit1, fruit2, fruit3];

    //add items to the cart
    Array.prototype.push.apply(theCart, bothFruits);
    //remove items from the cart by calling this function
    function removeAllItems() {
        if (theCart.length = !0) {
            theCart = [];
        }
    }
    //removeAllItems();  


    console.log(theCart);
}
```

}

Comment: This works great!

Only issue is that for the fruit3 column, the quantity is undefined, and the price is NAN:

Comment: For fruit3 you can try using this:

let fruit3 = new Fruits("Total amount", fruit1.price + fruit2.price, fruit1.quantity+ fruit2.quantity);

I'm not sure why you used fruit3 for the total calculation here.

Comment: Hi Roby, that is correct, I have now changed it and created a variable outside the array, as that makes a lot more sense. I just named it fruit3 for testing purposes. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

this now adds the total amount in a separate variable

```
module.exports = {
    shoppingCart: function () {
        //create empty cart array
        theCart = [];
        // create two seperate versions of the same kind of object using class method 
        class Fruits {
            constructor(fruit, price, quantity) {
                this.fruit = fruit;
                this.quantity = quantity;
                this.price = price * quantity;
                
            }
        }
        let fruit1 = new Fruits("Apple", 4.95, 2);       // create new object. sets the value of this
        let fruit2 = new Fruits("Orange", 3.99, 1);
        //let fruit3 = new Fruits("Total amount", fruit1.price * fruit2.price);
        // combine both fruits into an array
        let bothFruits = [fruit1, fruit2];
    
        //add items to the cart
        Array.prototype.push.apply(theCart, bothFruits);

        let total = fruit1.price + fruit2.price;
        //remove items from the cart by calling this function
        function removeAllItems() {
            if (theCart.length = !0) {
                theCart = [];
            }
        }
        //removeAllItems();  
    
    
        console.log(theCart, total);
    }
}
```